# SQL Sum If with Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, sum, case

I've got these tables:

> people(personID, name)
>
> expenses(personID, contract, labor, materials, travel, class)

The "class" column of the expenses table can have 3 options, a, b, or c. The three classes are another breakdown of how labor + materials + travel are used. So basically, labor + materials + travel = a + b + c. I just realized that maybe this table should be designed differently...maybe labor, materials, and travel, should also be a row item instead of a column. But anyway...

I would like to get this query:

```
PersonName, Contract, Labor, Materials, Travel, Total, A, B, C

Where Total = Labor + Materials + Travel = A + B + C
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

> ID, Contract, Labor, Materials, Travel, Class
>
> 1, Blockbuster, $10, $20, $30, 'A'
>
> 1, Blockbuster, $0, $15, $5, 'B'

I want to get this query at the end

> ID, Contract, Labor, Materials, Travel, Total, A, B
>
> 1, Blockbuster, $10, $35, $35, $80, $60, $20

Comment: Are Labor, Materials, Travel different for different classes? Can you post 3  example rows and row what you want to get?

Comment: Yes it is Viktor. Here are 3 example rows

PersonID, Contract, Labor, Materials, Travel, Class

[1, 1, $20, $30, $0, a]

[1, 1, $15, $45, $10, b]

[1, 2, $1, $0, $5, a]


And I would like to basically get a query that shows a sum for the labor, materials, and travel for the classes as well as it broken down as a sum for the person/contract

Comment: And how do you see result string for this 3 rows?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, that I can't understand how you want to select frields (PersonName, Contract, Labor, Materials, Travel, Total, A, B, C) from example data you've posted.  So thease 3 fields (Materials, Travel, Total) can be different for the same person and contract. How you want it to see in result? Like 2 different rows or like sum of values? That's why I also asked you to tell us, what you want to get in result for example.

Comment: And I also don't understand this condition (labor + materials + travel = a + b + c). (labor, materials, travel) has different value for every row of your table. And one row can have only one class. So it should be a(labor, materials, travel) and b(labor, materials, travel) and c(labor, materials, travel). What do you mean by this (labor + materials + travel = a + b + c) ? That  sum of this values for one class (for example for a)  should be equal to sum of b?

Comment: Just put few strings from your tables and result you want to get fom query (just data) and we try to understand how to do it in SQL

Comment: Viktor I just added an EDIT so you could see what I mean

Comment: Or let me know if you have a different idea on how the data should be stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, query, what you're looking for will be:

```
SELECT 
 (select name from people as p where p.personid=e.personID) AS name, 
 contract, 
 Sum(labor) AS sum_labor, 
 Sum(materials) AS sum_materials, 
 sum(travel) AS sum_travel, 
 Sum(Labor+Materials+Travel) AS total, 
 Sum(IIf(class='A',Labor+Materials+Travel,0)) AS A, 
 Sum(IIf(class='B',Labor+Materials+Travel,0)) AS B, 
 Sum(IIf(class='C',Labor+Materials+Travel,0)) AS C
FROM expenses as e
GROUP BY contract, personID;
```

About ideas how the data should be stored... Well, it's a complicated question.

If you want to collect data about changing, you should store previos values, when and who changed.

If you want to reach greater normalization in your data (for example for indexes, when you'll have a lot of data and reports), you should add type (Labor, Materials, Travel) and store amount of expenses in one column (i.e. columns will be personID, contract, type, class, amount).

and so on....

BUT! I don't know your task and don't know what goals you are achieving by this DataBase. If your current Data is enough - don't lose any sleep over it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Viktor. I am still pretty noob with SQL so t's super helpful seeing how you used the subquery SELECT within the main SELECT like that. Appreciate the help!